# How to hide paragraph which is behind this Player

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, blogger

[image]

See website url where i have embed :- `https://uuu77765.blogspot.com/p/1.html?m=1`

Or

Video `https://6d7ddd7.blogspot.com/?player=video&provider=gdrive&format=video%2Fmp4&link=1T_7bkD5xDQOtvYn2h8k7svxe7BR1ND0` link please check

I want that paragraph which is visible on top of player should disappear whenever player is on but that paragraph should appear on home page

[image]

Should not appear.